# Does HTTP Url connection require PORT opening in client side

Tags: java, get, port, httpurlconnection, firewall

I am calling GET method using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` . I was facing error "Connection refused "

I was calling `http://192.168.1.5:8038/GetStudent`

So wanted to understand do I need to open PORT *8038* in client side OS ?
I am confused because HTTP by default listen on 80 and which is OPEN.

I understand that in server side 8038 should be open

Comment: your web server is running on port 8038, for example by default most of web servers are running on port 8080 or weblogic is run on port 7001 but some one probably change the default of web server and config it on port 8038. usually in development process servers didnt run on port 80 and on your production server you change it to port 80, so in your case you should check if you could connect to port 8038 of server first(with commands like telnet) and if you could it is probably because your web application is not deployed on server that you get this error

Comment: Make sure server's firewall allows incoming connections on port 8038 and server is actually up and listening on that port. if your server is *nix based you can check process listening on 8038 using this command `netstat -tulpn | grep :8038`

Comment: I have tested from another machine and from browser I am able to get result from http://192.168.1.5:8038/GetStudent, but when I run the same using my code in My machine I am not getting result

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine on which port your server runs, because in your url, the part :8083 means that you try to connect to server port 8083, not on 80. In case where you not specify the port, then the default is 80. Maybe server is not running on this port (8083), or maybe there is a firewall blocking communication on it? There usually is no need for setting outgoing PORT on client side. The server could refuse when there is unknow user-agent property. Try to set user agent property like in this example:

```
        String url = "https://translate.google.pl/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=ro&tl=pl&hl=pl&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&ssel=4&tsel=3&kc=1&tk=521057|406131&q=";
        url = url + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
        con.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        // con.setha
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int n;
        while ((n = con.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(n);
        }
        ;

        String translatedText = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have tested from another machine and from browser I am able to get result from http://192.168.1.5:8038/GetStudent, but when I run the same using my code in My machine I am not getting result

Comment: Is your machine in the same subnet as the server?

Comment: To help, what is your own IP?

Comment: Yes same subnet, My friends IP 192.168.1.70 and My IP is 192.168.1.45